# For Loop C#-- Adding

Tags: c#, for-loop, addition

How to find a loop that will successfully add 5 numbers. Here is the homework question.

1. Add a loop that will take a number input by the user and add it to a running total (the ReadLine() method will get a string from the user).

You’ll notice in the above code there are two variables declared.
One is total of the double data type which will have the total of the 5 entered numbers.
The other is a temp string variable to take the user input, convert to double, and then add the converted value to the total.

Using what you have learned in case 2 about taking input and converting to an int32, take the input and convert ToDouble() instead of int32.
total = total + Convert.ToDouble(temp);

```
    case "3":
    double total = 0;
    string temp = "0";
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 numbers here for addition \n");
    for (total = 0; total <= 6; total++);
    {
        Console.WriteLine(total + "" + temp);
        total = total + Convert.ToDouble(temp);
    }
    break;
```

When I tried entering this in, the debugging program exited out and gave me a set number.
It keeps saying that string will not convert to integer when I tried entering string as an expressions instead.

Here is the result I am trying to get.

1
2
3
4
5
Total:15 This is the answer I am trying to get.

Comment: Please show your real code. This code doesn't compile. Your code treats `input` as a `string` (when being assigned the return value of `Console.ReadLine()`) and as an `int` (when using it in the `for` loop).

Comment: alright here is the original code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

You set temp to be an empty string and then it never becomes a number, hence you can't cast it to a double....

Convert.ToDouble(input) won't do anything either as you need to store the value, i.e.

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble (input)
```

The loop is wrong because you only ever take one input - you need to put your Console.ReadLine in your loop and then append what the user inputs to your total.

Comment: how would i set it to a number?

Comment: Add a loop that will take a number input by the user and add it to a running total (the ReadLine() method will get a string from the user).  You’ll notice in the above code there are two variables declared.  One is total of the double data type which will have the total of the 5 entered numbers.  The other is a temp string variable to take the user input, convert to double, and then add the converted value to the total.  Using what you have learned in case 2 about taking input and converting to an int32, take the input and convert ToDouble() instead of int32.

Comment: Also, Convert.ToDouble(input) won't work with five numbers in a string, it only works on one number at a time. Plus, the results of the conversion aren't being saved currently.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to do:

```
int index=Convert.ToDouble(input);
```

and use in the for loop something like

```
for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
```

since as it stands you retrieve an input but don't use it, in for loop in fact you're trying to set it to zero -> for(input=0;....)
which can't be done since input is a string and not a number

in case 3 you're using total as an index and as the total variable in the calculation you can't do that
you need another variable to use as a index:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= 6; i++);
    {
        Console.WriteLine(total + "" + temp);
        total = total + Convert.ToDouble(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Won't compile. `input` is either a `string` or `object`. Both cases will yield different compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.Write("Enter how many numbers you want to enter and sum up: ");

        double n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
        double r;  
        double sum = 0;  


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        {  
            Console.Write("{0} Enter number ", i);  
            r = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            sum += r;  
            Console.WriteLine(sum);  
        }
```